# PowerShell - Refering to variable outside for loop

Tags: windows, powershell, office365

I may just be doing this in an idiotic manner, but i am trying to call a variable that is outside a for loop called $CSV which is an imported CSV file.

I think i just have the syntax wrong. I know when you are referring to a variable outside sometimes need to refer to the variable as $*Name or $*.Name depending. But neither of those seem to work.

```
 Write-Host "Start Process"
 $E3Stage2= New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId  EnvistaForensics:ENTERPRISEPACK -DisabledPlans BPOS_S_TODO_2, FORMS_PLAN_E3, STREAM_O365_E3, Deskless, FLOW_O365_P2, POWERAPPS_O365_P2, TEAMS1, PROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT, SWAY, INTUNE_O365, YAMMER_ENTERPRISE, MCOSTANDARD
 $CSV = Import-csv "Input.csv" 
 $CSVStat = $CSV | Measure-Object

  For ( $i=0; $i -lt $CSVStat.Count; $i++)  { 
    Write-Host "Assigning License for user  ---- $CSV.EmailAddress[$i]"
    Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $CSV.EmailAddress[$i] -LicenseOptions $E3Stage2
                                            }

    Write-Progress "waiting six minutes" -Status "Please Wait"
    Start-Sleep 360

  For ( $i=0; $i -lt $CSVStat.Count; $i++)  { 
    Write-Host "enabling litigation hold for user ---- $CSV.EmailAddress[$i]"
    Set-Mailbox -identity $CSV.EmailAddress[$i] -LitigationHoldEnabled $true

                                            } 



    Write-Host "Final User done script completed"
```

in the for loop the it cannot find $CSV and error out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things:

1. `$Csv` already has a .count property, no need to Measure-Object
2. The for could be replaced by a

```
$csv | ForEach-Object {$_.EmailAddress}
```

or

```
ForeEach ($Row in $Csv){ $Row.EmailAddress}
```

3. To expand $Variable.Property inside a string use `"$($Variable.Property)"`

Comment: Wow it does, let me rewrite this quickly with the foreach-object and without the measure-object.

Comment: The first one `$csv | ForEach-Object {$_.EmailAddress}` seems to work. still giving me a bit of trouble. the Set-MsolUserLicense is saying the variable is null the full section is     `$CSV | ForEach-Object { 
        Write-Host "Assigning License for user  ---- $_.CSV.EmailAddress"
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.CSV.EmailAddress -LicenseOptions $E3Stage2
                                                }`

Comment: `$_.CSV.EmailAddress` is wrong, use `$_.EmailAddress` The currently processed item is `$_`

Comment: do you know why they use `$_.` syntax and when to user it?

Comment: [Get-Help about_foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-5.1)